# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - and - ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, node.js-got

I'm attempting to create some API tests with Jestjs and Gotjs and typescript.  Below is my snippet for initial.test.ts

```
import { got } from "got";

test('initial got jest test', async () => {
    const url = 'https://httpbin.org/anything';
    const response = await got(url);
});
```

This is giving me an error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

No, problem.  There appears to be a published solution.   Add the following to the package.json

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Well, after adding that to the package.json, and running the script I have a new error:

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/christopher.carignan/Desktop/sunrun/testAutomation/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

This is really weird.   Am I making the correct change to the packagae.json ?

Comment: `module.exports` should be changed to `export default` when using ESM. CommonJS and ESM mismatch.

Comment: Yea, I did that and I'm still getting that error :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in index.d.ts file

```
declare module 'got' {
const content: any;
export default content;}
```

Folder Structure:

[image]

tsconfig file: (Add the folder to typeRoots parameter)

[image]